# python urllib2.urlopen(url) process block

Tags: python, urlopen

I am using `urllib2.urlopen()` and my process is getting blocked

I am aware that `urllib2.urlopen()` has default timeout.

How to make the call unblockable?

The backtrace is

```
(gdb) bt 
#0 0x0000003c6200dc35 in recv () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0 
#1 0x00002b88add08137 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_socketmodule.so 
#2 0x00002b88add0830e in ?? () from /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_socketmodule.so 
#3 0x000000310b2d8e19 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0
```

Comment: You'll want to post the actual code that is blocking. urlopen blocks until it receives a response or raises a timeout error. Without seeing your code nobody can tell why it isn't raising the timeout error.

Comment: what error messages do you see? could you post the code that is raising the error?

Comment: What is your client connecting to? Is it a HTTP web server? Is it producing a response (urlopen will hang until it gets something)? What happens if you connect with another http client, e.g. curl?

Answer (score 3):

**If your problem is that you need to urllib to finish reading**

read() operation is blocking operation in Python.

If you want to create asynchronous requests

- Do reading in non-main thread http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html
- Use `requests`library and asynchronous requests http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#asynchronous-requests

**If your problem is need to set timeout**

Again, use `requests` library as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [`strace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) (or similar) tool to figure out what the actual *system* call is that is blocking your python script, e.g on linux: `$ strace python yourscript.py`

yourscript.py:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
urlopen("http://somesite.local/foobar.html")
```

`$ strace python yourscript.py`

```
... lots of system call stripped ...
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(80), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16
```

Comment: (gdb) bt
#0  0x0000003c6200dc35 in recv () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0

#1  0x00002b88add08137 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_socketmodule.so

#2  0x00002b88add0830e in ?? () from /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_socketmodule.so

#3  0x000000310b2d8e19 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0